# Using a single matrix as multiple input arguments to a function

Tags: matlab, function, input

Is there any way to use a matrix for MULTIPLE input argument of a function?

Example:

```
x=-10:0.1:10; 
a=[1 2];
normpdf(x,a);
```

instead of 
normpdf(x, a(1), a(2));

I can do it with eval, in this way

```
for i=1:nargin(@normalpdf)-1 %in order to get parameter size, taking out the first one which for a pdf is usually x
    if i>1
        str=[str ','];
    end
    str=[str 'x(' num2str(i) ')'];
end
normpdf(x, eval(str));
```

However, I was wondering if there is any way to do the same without using eval.

EDIT: I want to be clear. Of course if a matrix is defined as fun(a, b) where b is a matrix, this is trivial. But can i use a matrix with more then one element where EACH ELEMENT IS A INPUT ARGUMENT OF THE FUNCTION? (like in the example)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One other option would be to use a cell array to generate a [comma separated list](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/comma-separated-lists.html):

```
x=-10:0.1:10; 
a={1,2};
normpdf(x,a{:});
```

Comment: that's exactly what i was looking for. A lot easier than expected. Thank you!

Comment: @Vaaal But is it really worth doing it this way? You should consider readability thoroughly before opting for this method. Especially with only two parameters.

Comment: Hello Dan. I know that it seems really an unusual way of doing so. However, consider this problem: 
I want to call a function with n parameter. I want flexibility, so I may change the function easily. I will evaluate the function at run time with eval. As for the parameters, I want to evaluate them at run time too, since depending on the function they may change.

Yes, the redeability decrease, but the flexibility increases a lot.

Answer (score 0):

If you produce your own functions of course a matrix can be an argument. But in this specific case the functions has been written to accept scalar arguments. So you must give the two variables a(1) and a(2) comma separated.